# Movie about a concave (Hollow) world

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction, fantasy

A movie about a man ending up in a concave or (Hollow) world think the movie was Russian or  Eastern European. Pretty sure the movie was made since 2000 but not 100% sure. I remember him talking to a women about the concave world (she was a native of that place) and her being confused when he talked about his world. I only saw the trailers so don't have much info.

Answer (score 6):

[image: The Inhabited Island (2008) - Movie Poster 01] [image: The Inhabited Island (2008) - Movie Poster 02]

[**The Inhabited Island** (2008)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0972558/)

> The film is set in the year 2157, following the exploits of a young
>   earthling named Maksim who unexpectedly crash lands on an uncharted
>   yet fully populated planet.

[image: The Inhabited Island (2008) - Pic 01]

> Maksim, now a stranger in a strange land, must figure out how to
>   survive in this hostile new world while simultaneously bringing about
>   a revolution against an oppressive government that controls its
>   citizens by use of an elaborate form of mind control.

[image: The Inhabited Island (2008) - Pic 02]

It's odd but most of the reviews I've read don't mention the "hollowness'' of the planet (shown in the first pic). Some [details](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/PrisonersOfPower) from the book the movie was based on:

> The protagonist, Maxim Kammerer, is stranded on the world of Saraksh
>   where **the atmosphere has such an enormous refraction index that the
>   horizon seems to bend upwards**.

Here's a bit more on that:

> **Saraksh's skyline must look really bizarre** to a Terran. The
>   atmosphere's chemical composition results in total lack of clear
>   skies, and somehow distorts optics to the point where the planet's
>   surface appears concave instead of convex, making it seem **as if the
>   planet is actually the interior of a giant bubble**.

<sup>*~ Posters from [IMP Awards](http://www.impawards.com/intl/russia/2008/obitaemyy_ostrov.html) and [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/media/rm3166934784/tt0972558?ref_=tt_ov_i); Stills from [SCIFI-Movies](http://www.scifi-movies.com/english/photos-0001215-3-the-inhabited-island-2-2009.htm)*</sup>

Watch one of the [trailers](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ojw7I016Puw) to confirm. There's also an English-dubbed [promo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1kl4MrwBwhU).

**Note**: "The Inhabited Island" is actually a two-parter. More details on the second half [here](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1399952/) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Inhabited_Island).